# Is it possible to pass Function to ExecutorService instead of callable in Java 8?

Tags: java-8, future, executorservice, callable

```
public class myService {

    @Autowired
    ExecutorService executor;

    public Result getServiceResult(Token token, Profile profile){
        //validate token and profile
        return getResult(token, profile).get();
    }

    private getResult (Token token, Profile profile){
       Future<Result> = threadPoolExecutor.submit(
               () -> myManager.createAccount(token, profile));
    }
}
```

This code runs fine at my current work. I am not able to able to understand how `threadPoolExecutor.submit` is passed a "Function/Method" but not a `callable`?

I am using Java 8 and Spring framework.

Comment: Why do you thing a Function is passed?

Comment: @JBNizet: can you elaborate?

Comment: What makes you think the code you posted passes a Function to submit()? Given http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html, what makes you think submit() accepts a Function? Given that there is only one documented submit() method returning a `Future<T>` in ExecutorService, what do you think the type of `() -> myManager.createAccount(token, profile)` is?

Comment: @JBNizet: `mymanager.createAccount` takes two arguments `token` and `profile` and returns object of type `result`.  Since Java 8, supports passing function, I thought we are passing function. But I am not clear now what is being passed? can you help?

Comment: What is passed is an instanceof Callable<Result>. This Callable<Result> instance is written as a lambda expression. Explaining how lambdas work would be much too broad here. Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html, and google for the bazillions of articles about Java 8 lambdas and functional interfaces. A Function and a lambda expression are not the same thing. Function is a new (functional) interface in Java 8. But any functional interface instance, not just Function, can be expressed as a lambda expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to know why you seem to be able to pass a "Function" to the [`ThreadPoolExecutor.submit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#submit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) method that takes a [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html), not a [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html).

The explanation is that the method *can't* take a `Function` as a parameter; what you're seeing is a `Callable` being passed in, expressed as a [*`lambda` expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) (Essentially an expression that uses the right arrow (`->`) syntax).

As outlined in the previous document, a lambda expression is used to provide an implementation of an interface that has exactly one abstract method that is not an override of a method on `Object`. These are typically annotated [`FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), which is possibly where your confusion arose, although this is not a requirement as outlined in [the Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8):

> A *functional interface* is an interface that has just one abstract 
>   method (aside from the methods of `Object`), and thus represents a single 
>   function contract. This "single" method may take the form of multiple 
>   abstract methods with override-equivalent signatures inherited from 
>   superinterfaces; in this case, the inherited methods logically represent 
>   a single method.

In your example above, depending on the return type of `myManager.createAccount()`, you're either providing an implementation of `Callable` (if you return anything), or [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) if it's a `void` method:

```
() -> myManager.createAccount(token, profile)
```

Your lambda matches the method signature of the abstract [`call()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html#call--) or [`run()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html#run--) methods because it takes no parameters (As indicated by the `()` on the left hand side of the arrow), and returns `void` or some result.

Comment: I was reading about `functionalInterface` annotion. It is this which makes it possible to pass lambda. But you mention that  `functionalInterface` annotion is not a requirement. why is it so?

Comment: @brainstorm I've added the relevant section of the JLS outlining what a Functional Interface actually is, but if you look at the JavaDoc for the FunctionalInterface annotation (linked above) it states it's not required and is just a convenience.